# Ionic app runs on android but getting plugin_not_installed error for multiple plugins on iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

My app runs on android fine but using the same plugins the app gives multiple plugin_not_installed errors for various plugins

error:

```
[Warning] Ionic Native: tried calling HTTP.setDataSerializer, but the HTTP plugin is not installed. (vendor.js, line 61253)
[Warning] Install the HTTP plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http' (vendor.js, line 61265)
[Warning] 'Ionic Native: tried accessing the SecureStorage plugin but it's not installed. (vendor.js, line 61262)
[Warning] Install the SecureStorage plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-secure-storage' (vendor.js, line 61265)
[Warning] Ionic Native: tried calling AppVersion.getAppName, but the AppVersion plugin is not installed. (vendor.js, line 61253)
[Warning] Install the AppVersion plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-version' (vendor.js, line 61265)
[Warning] Ionic Native: tried calling HTTP.setDataSerializer, but the HTTP plugin is not installed. (vendor.js, line 61253)
[Warning] Install the HTTP plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http' (vendor.js, line 61265)
[Warning] Ionic Native: tried calling HTTP.setSSLCertMode, but the HTTP plugin is not installed. (vendor.js, line 61253)
[Warning] Install the HTTP plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http' (vendor.js, line 61265)
[Warning] Ionic Native: tried calling HTTP.post, but the HTTP plugin is not installed. (vendor.js, line 61253)
[Warning] Install the HTTP plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http' (vendor.js, line 61265)
```

Steps already taken:

- Fresh node_modules, plugins, platforms folder
- Tested on cordova-ios 4.5.4 and cordova-ios 5.0.1
- checked both plugin and npm dependencies are installed.
- made sure to call native commands after isPlatformReady()

Ionic:

```
   Ionic CLI          : 5.2.8 (/Users/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.2, (and 21 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.6.0 (update available: 0.8.0)
   native-run  : 0.2.8 

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/xx/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   ios-sim           : 8.0.1
   NodeJS            : v10.14.0 (/Users/xx/.nvm/versions/node/v10.14.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.5.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.1 Build version 11A1027
```

Plugins installed:

```
com.adjust.sdk 4.18.0 "Adjust"
cordova-clipboard 1.3.0 "Clipboard"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 2.0.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.2.0 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.9 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-firebase-lib 5.1.1 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.1.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-is-debug 1.0.0 "IsDebug"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.3 "Media"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 3.0.3 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-secure-storage 3.0.2 "SecureStorage"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.6.0 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"
```

Comment: You should check if folder has proper permission and then try to remove platform for ios then install again, but if still not working then get the list of plugins those are not installed for ios and install them manually. Sometimes plugin will not install for ios then use "--force" to install them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best solution when I face weird errors is to clean and reset the project

- delete folders: node_modules, platform, plugins, www
- install dependencies again using `npm i`
- run `ionic cordova run ios`

package.json holds all dependency and plugin information to recover the project

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issues and the solution has usually been to delete the plugin folder and run `cordova prepare` from the terminal.